# Display wordpress post to static website in the footer

Tags: php, html

I am a totally fresh with wordpress I have this website : http://www.raminusa.com/ in footer there is a column name "Popular Link" and I want to replace it with Recent News that I will do but below this heading I need my first 5 or 4 recent post from my wordpress blog.

My wordpress blog is : http://immigrationstatus.wordpress.com

I do not know how is it possible can some one help me with this.

Here is the code I used:

```
<?php 
    $url = "http://immigrationstatus.wordpress.com/rss2/";
    require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss-functions.php');
    $rss = fetch_rss($url);
?>
<ul class="footer-links">
    <?php
        foreach ($rss->items as $item ) {
            echo "<li><a href='".$item['link']."' title='".$item['title']".'>".$item['title']."</a></li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** After a brief chat with Original Poster, the following solution works:

- Install the [Magpie RSS library](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/).
- Create a folder in the root directory of `raminusa.com`, name it *magpierss*
- Upload 4 files (*rss_fetch.inc*, *rss_parser.inc*, *rss_cache.inc*, and *rss_utils.inc*), and the directory *extlib* to this new folder

In the footer script of `raminusa.com` (which should be in the same directory as the newly created *magpierss* folder), add the following script.

```
<?php
    $url = "http://immigrationstatus.wordpress.com/feed/";
    require_once('magpierss/rss_fetch.inc');
    $rss = fetch_rss($url);
?>
<ul class="footer-links">
    <?php
                if($rss) {
                        foreach ($rss->items as $item ) {
                                $link = $item['link'];
                                $title = $item['title'];
                                echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
                        }
                } else {
                        echo '<li>Sorry, RSS Feed could not be loaded</li>';
                }
    ?>
</ul>
```

To change the amount of links shown, go to your WordPress installation, and go to Settings > Reading. Change the value for *Syndication feeds show the most recent*. The default is 10 most recent posts.

Comment: Thanks Marc I applied what you said but it is giving me this error: http://raminusa.com/rss.php

Comment: Can you provide the contents of rss.php in your original post? It would help determine what exactly goes wrong on line 9.

Comment: ok wait I am giving it to you

Comment: I posted it check now

Comment: I have edited my answer. It saves the array elements in separate variables before using them in the `echo` line.

Comment: It is again giving errors this time on line no. 3

Comment: Line 3 imports the required script. Are you loading this code in the footer template of WordPress? If you try to run this code outside a WordPress template page it won't work because it won't understand what `WPINC` is. The code I provided is to replace whatever code you currently have in your footer for the "Popular Link" column, as you mentioned you want to **replace** that column.

Comment: Do I have to replace your code with my footer content

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7894/discussion-between-marc-dingena-and-kennethel)